# How does windows implement user mode /kernel mode?

Tags: windows, kernel

From the aspect of programe, how is done?

How can it avoid user mode programe to load kernel modules and call its functions?

Comment: This is a super broad question. This book will have your answers: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901 Or try to be a little more specific in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Virtual memory.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)

Unprivileged processes simply can't reach the kernel data structures and code, because there are no corresponding page table entries.  And the CPU prevents unprivileged processes from swapping the page table.

Comment: How does it know whether a process is privileged or not?This must be done by some kind of flags,but how can OS ensure the process doesn't fake the flags itself?

Comment: @kern: Processes are unprivileged.  There are flag bits in the CPU that the OS sets when switching to a user-mode task, and changing those flag bits requires a privileged instruction, it is enforced by the CPU itself.  The way those flag bits get unset is during interrupt service routines.  FOr example, the task scheduler runs in the timer ISR, so it is privileged and can update the page table to match the process which is about to start running.  The flags are set to unprivileged again when the ISR completes.

Comment: Every privileged routine is reached by an interrupt, either hardware interrupt or software interrupt (syscall), except early in the boot process when the timer ISR and syscall handlers are installed.  And only privileged routines can install interrupt handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Read about Rings of protection

Hardware view 
:
1)  There is a bit in a control register that is different (say 0=kernel, 1=user). 
2)  Hardware access to devices is usually unavailable in user mode. 
3)  Some instructions are available only in kernel mode. 
4)  Modifications to the page tables are only possible in kernel mode. 
5)  The interrupt controller can only be modified in kernel mode. 
6)  Other hardware control registers (such as system time, timer control, etc) are available 
only in kernel mode. 
7)  Kernel memory is not available to users in user mode.

copied from cs162 p sets